# HAProxy with mysql-check option, not working

Tags: mysql, haproxy

I have added an entry to my HAProxy connection to connect to a MySQL database. It is only for reading at present, not writing.

I have set it up as follows:

```
frontend db_read_port33517
mode    tcp
option  tcplog
bind *:33517
default_backend db_slave_con

backend db_slave_con
option  mysql-check user haproxy post-41

   server database1   1.2.3.4:3307 check port 3307
   server database2   1.2.3.5:3307 check port 3307 backup
```

It is MySQL 5.7, and I have added a basic user to MySQL:

```
CREATE USER 'haproxy'@'1.0.0.0/255.0.0.0' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

But looking at the the stats page, it can't connect to either database. This is the first time I have used the `mysql-check` option, but I'm guessing I have missed something, but having been through all the notes I can't see what it is?

n.b. the databases both exist, and I can connect to them with the `haproxy` user..

---

Looking in the logs, I can see I am getting `0Access denied for user 'haproxy'@'1.2.3.6'`. I have modified the user to be `haproxy@%` but that makes no difference.

I am guessing that it is because the user was created with a password, (our policy dictates all database users must have a password) and HAProxy isn't passing across the password. Is there a way to specify the password in the HAProxy config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I was right, as soon as I removed the password, HAProxy could see the databases. I've gone through the notes for HAProxy, and there doesn't appear to be any way to specify a password.

Whilst I appreciate it is only using that user to connect / disconnect this still seems like a bit of a security issue, as I now have a user in my database with no password. The best I can do for now I think is lock down the IP Address for the user as tightly as possible.

Comment: A created user by default has no access to anything. Looks ugly without a password, but isn't actually a risk. `create user 'haproxy'@'10.0.2.100' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 1 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0;` might make some people feel better about it. MariaDB 10.2+ has [MAX_STATEMENT_TIME](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#resource-limit-options) that can be set down in the microsecond range. `ACCOUNT LOCK` and `PASSWORD EXPIRE` options are incompatible with the ha-proxy check.